rafter support with support beam
I have a vary old house with a detached, double car garage. The garage has seven (7) 2x6x22' rafters, which gives approximately 3 feet spacing. The rafters are sagging a little and I would like to support them. The garage is 22'x22'.
My thoughs are:

Install middle support beam, being 22' long. A thickness of three 2x10x12', making up 22', scabbed together, or 2x12x12'. Of course running perpendicular to the rafters and supported on each end.
Sister each 2x6x22'
Add an addition 2x6x22 in between the existing 2x6's.

The space in the garage attic is not an occupied space. My plans are to use it for some storage.
So, my questions are; are my plans adequate, if so, should I use 2X12's , or are 2X10's enough.
Do I need a middle support for the new support beam.
Thank You

Got any pics to share?

Or even better, drawings? They don't have to be fancy or even square, just have to show the dimensions and spacing of what you have now and where you plan on this new support going

I imagine by 22 ft you mean the boards going wall to wall(joists) and not rafters holding the roof deck.  A 22ft beam should have a middle/close to middle support post.  The concern is the floor and if it can hold the post.  For just storage/holding up sag, a large foot/base might be enough, instead of a proper footing
